# jquery not send more then 1 values

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on project that when someone scrolls the page down, it loads more items. The  problem is when I use jquery to send two values via get in the url, it does not work.Wwhen items load then they do not work properly because php is not getting any value via jquery. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function last_msg_funtionc() 
{ 

   var ID=$(".productsc:last").attr("id");
   var CID=$(".productsc").attr("cid");
    $.post("categories.php?action=get&last_msg_id=+ID&cid="+CID,

    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".productsc:last").after(data);           
        }
        $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
    });
};

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       last_msg_funtionc();
    }
}); 
});
```

And  when I send a single value this 'last_msg_id' it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?
my php code is

```
<?php
require_once'config.php';
$last_msg_id=$_POST['last_msg_id'];
$action=$_POST['action'];

if($action <> "get")
{
include_once'categories_first.php';
}
else
{

include'categories_second.php';

        }
```

amd categorys_first.php is not need to conect with jquery . jquerye get last id from categories_first.php. and now this is categories_second.php jquery send cid to this file
code is

```
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
$get_item=mysql_query('select * from items where cid="'.$_GET['cid'].'" and id < "'.$last_msg_id.'" order by id desc limit 4');
$last_msg_id='';
//another code here
```

Comment: why don't you use the post methods native data property to send your parameters? So you'd avoid wrong escaped characters...

Comment: set all your variables to use either $_GET or $_POST then use the corresponding jquery function

Comment: i just use $_GET alll files.

Comment: You have post in action and last_msg_id at the beginning of categories.php, did you change those? What happened then?

Comment: no they work like. jquery send action and last_msg_id. and categories.php get those values and if not. then load categores_second.php file and categories_second.php get cid and last_msg_id from jquery. and last_msg id maybe work fine_bud cid not work bcoz i did not get right item order of cid.(categorie id) and when i echo $_GET['cid']; i dont get any out put like. php know cid but not get cid value.

Comment: What function are you using in jquery to send the values? What I'm saying is either change those two $_POST you have to $_GET or change the $_GETs in categories_second to $_POST

Comment: @user2628408 add `alert(CID);` before your ajax call, my guess is that its not sending the variable because it doesn't exist

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey when i add cid attr in categories_forst.php then get ine popup alert  vlaue is 1<-= and is work bcoz categoris id is 1  but how i send this vlaue to categories_second.php ???  when i echo $_GET['cid']; in second_category. i didnot get any vlaue. also not get any error. but when i remove cid in jquery. then i get error. undefined index cid in categories.php_second. online. 8

Comment: @koala_dev i am tryng as you as you say. and try to echo $_POST['cid']; and nothing result found

Comment: if i past all my data php and jquery in my question ?. is ok or any not allow ??

Comment: Yes you can post all relevant code. You do see the relation between the jquery code and your php? In my answer I send all data through get, so you wont get any in post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code which has been updated

```
$.post("categories.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID+"&cid="+CID,
```

Here is how you should be doing this since you are not POSTing

```
$.get('categories.php', {'action':'get','last_msg_id':ID,'cid':CID}, function(data){ // your code });
```

Comment: no work geting php error undefine index cid on categories.php
and i was using this downlaod scirpt and its default use get method. with php. last msg id with jquery its work and php get this using get method. but why cid not work ???

Comment: @user2628408 you need to update your answer with your PHP code so we can take a look, and point to the line number you are getting the error on.

Answer (score 1):

correct line:

```
$.post("categories.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID+"&cid="+CID,
```

Comment: how do you get those values in PHP?

Comment: USING GET method. and last_msg_id php get fine. but not get cid

Comment: `var CID=$(".productsc").attr("cid"); `

do you have `cid="..."` attribute on your `.productsc` item? add  `alert(CID)` to check if this is correct data - also assure that there is only 1 item with class `productsc`

Comment: hi i add aler for cid. i get reply Undefined.

Comment: eh - not alert(cid) or but alert(CID). also you are sure that you have only one productsc class?

Comment: yeh ALERT(CID); <-=  i have just one class but file are 2 and same class. when i use cid and cid attr just use in categopries_second.php i get undefined alert. but add cid in categories_first.php . then get cid perfect. popup says 1 <- which is right i know. and but i echo $_GET['cid']; IN php but php not show cid value. in second categories file.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks like the ID var isn't outside of the quoted statement:

"categories.php?action=get&last_msg_id=+ID&cid="+CID

Try this:
"categories.php?action=get&last_msg_id=" +ID +"&cid="+CID

Answer (score 0):

Use `.get()` since you're not actually sending any values through $_POST

```
var ID=$(".productsc:last").attr("id");
var CID=$(".productsc").attr("cid");
$.get("categories.php",
    {
        action: 'get',
        last_msg_id: ID,
        cid: CID
    },
    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            $(".productsc:last").after(data);           
        }
        $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
});
```

Comment: change = to : in last_msg_id and cid

Comment: thnaks for replayng gyus but php not looks @ cid value. just php know geting cid . not cid value

Comment: it would be easier to just use $_GET or $_POST for all your variables, then use the corresponding jquery function $.get() or $.post() they have the same syntax

Comment: Thanks To All Guyz actualyy i mix up the 2 jquery scripts. thast y getting problems:- )) now work fine :- ))